# How can I debug or run a Blackberry project done using ant?

Tags: debugging, ant, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am working on a project which has ant files to build the project. I newer worked with ant before. Please help me with how to run or debug this app in simulator. A good doc for running and debugging applications with Ant in BB would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Ant is more of a build tool and not really intended to be used to debug projects.  Yes, Ant can execute a task but it sounds like you need an IDE that can debug your Blackberry project rather than mentioning or concentrating on Ant.

Comment: I am using Blackberry plugin for eclipse as an IDE. And i was not able to debug it using IDE, since the build of this package is done by ant file.